# Notation for removing one column and one row from a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I need some notation for removing row $r$ and column $c$ from a matrix.  I tried

$$
M_{(r,c)^-}
$$

but it doesn't look right. For clarity, if $M$ is $n \times n$ then $M_{(r,c)^-}$ is $n-1 \times n-1$.

Is there any known notation for this operation or does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The determinant of such a matrix is called as [Minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra))

Answer (score 0):

The notation I know is $M^{(r,c)}$, however I do not claim that this is the unique one. I think it would be best to choose what you feel most comfortable with and properly define it in your work.

Comment: The minor, as defined, is the *determinant* of the smaller matrix required, not the matrix itself.

Comment: Ah, damn, you are right, sorry. I will edit it.

Comment: In general if $I$ and $J$ are (ordered) subsets of the row and column indices then $m_{IJ}$ for the submatrix usually does the trick, as it is easy to keep track of subsequent operations, but here I'd write $m_{\hat{r}\hat{c}}$. (Lower case because we usually use l.c. for the entries.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician Why don't you propose your comment as an answer? It looks quite reasonable.